# Centering input values and labels in Bootstrap input-group-append class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center everything in a form, with the labels and the values in input fields. This works, except when using the input-group-append class in Bootstrap. The input field and the appended button is treated as one and the entire thing is centered. How can I center just the input field?

It looks like this:

[image]

My code:

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
  <div class="form-group boxed">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label class="label" for="firstname">Name</label>
        <input name="firstname" class="form-control"  style="text-align:center"type="text" value="john">
    </div>
</div>      
<div class="form-group boxed">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label class="label" for="email">E-mail</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:center" value="info@domain.com">
            <span class="input-group-append numspan">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need such a result? - https://ibb.co/KyyX4d8

Comment: You will have to add additional left padding (width of label) to your input field. Since this is variable, you will most likely have to use javascript.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov, yes exactly that :)